# Keep getting this error when assigning ItemSource for MvxListView, stumped

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is happening during runtime when I try to assign the collection to the  ItemsSource, the program claims the method below is referenced but dosn't exist.  Not sure what's going on.

```
[] Missing method Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods::WeakSubscribe(INotifyCollectionChanged,EventHandler`1<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>) in assembly /data/data/CraigsJobs.Application/files/.__override__/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll, referenced in assembly /data/data/CraigsJobs.Application/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll
[MvxBind]   1.01 Problem seen during binding execution for from Categories to ItemsSource - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Here is the full trace:

```
[] Missing method Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods::WeakSubscribe(INotifyCollectionChanged,EventHandler`1<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>) in assembly /data/data/CraigsJobs.Application/files/.__override__/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll, referenced in assembly /data/data/CraigsJobs.Application/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll
[MvxBind]   1.01 Problem seen during binding execution for from Categories to ItemsSource - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
[MvxBind]     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MvxBind]   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MvxBind]   at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MvxBind]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MvxBind]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MvxBind] InnerException was MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe'.
[MvxBind]     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00001] in d:\MVVMCross\MvvmCross\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid\Views\MvxAdapter.cs:71 
[MvxBind]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00001] in d:\MVVMCross\MvvmCross\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid\Views\MvxListView.cs:56 
[MvxBind]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
[MvxBind]   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
MvxBind:Error:  1.01 Problem seen during binding execution for from Categories to ItemsSource - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
InnerException was MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe'.
      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00001] in d:\MVVMCross\MvvmCross\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid\Views\MvxAdapter.cs:71 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.set_ItemsSource (IEnumerable value) [0x00001] in d:\MVVMCross\MvvmCross\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid\Views\MvxListView.cs:56 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
[] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x987c8b8, tid 10935
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
[libEGL] loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
[EGL_emulation] eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: I got it working.  I just needed to rebuild all the mvvmcross libraries under the same android version and organize them properly.  Also I wasn't invoking this call on the UI thread.

Comment: At a **guess** you **maybe** somehow had different versions of mvvmcross assemblies present - the weak referencing has (in the last few weeks) moved from `binding` to `CrossCore`. Glad a rebuild all solved this for you.

Comment: @mikegold: can you please post this as an answer to your question and mark it answered?